# Simple VBA selection: Selecting 5 cells to the right of the active cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to select and a row of 5 cells to the right (the selection should include my active cell) of my active cell. My current code is:

```
Sub SelectandCopy()
'
' SelectandCopy Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+C
'
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Study.xlsx").Activate
End Sub
```

I do want not a specific range from my worksheet because I want to be able to make a selection of these data sets from anywhere within my worksheet. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Would you use the Selection.Extend?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This copies the 5 cells to the right of the activecell. If you have a range selected, the active cell is the top left cell in the range.

```
Sub Copy5CellsToRight()
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 5).Copy
End Sub
```

If you want to include the activecell in the range that gets copied, you don't need the offset:

```
Sub ExtendAndCopy5CellsToRight()
    ActiveCell.Resize(1, 6).Copy
End Sub
```

Note that you don't need to select before copying.

Comment: This did the trick, but it didn't copy the my current active cell.

Comment: See my edited answer. The second version will include your current active cell.

Answer (score 2):

This example selects a new `Range` of `Cells` defined by the current cell to a cell 5 to the right.

Note that `.Offset` takes arguments of `Offset(row, columns)` and can be quite useful.

---

```
Sub testForStackOverflow()
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5)).Copy
End Sub
```